# findBy( ) methods not getting displayed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use Spring data JPA **find** inbuilt methods.
I want to use findByName() , findByDescription but as of now findById() is the only method getting displayed for me.

This is my Entity class.

```
 package com.sood1.springdata.product.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String desc;
    
    private Double price;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

This is my Repository

```
package com.sood1.springdata.product.repos;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.sood1.springdata.product.entities.Product;

public interface ProductRepo extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

Can anyone suggest why **findByName**()  or other **find** methods not coming for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare a method in the repository interface like

```
List<Product> findProductByName(final string name);
```

or something like that

Johan

Comment: Hi Balimam ,  ideally all find methods should come by hitting ctrl + space.
But it's not happening for me.